# handle fcm display messages and data messages by using laravel rest api in android java

Tags: laravel-5, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

*how to handle it in android fcm please share any suitable solution i
 want to resolve issue of fcm on background and on foreground*

```
$payload = [
  'to' => $user->device_token,
  'collapse_key'      =>'test message',
  'data' => [
    'title' => '',
    'message' => $push_message
  ],
  'notiification' => [
    'title' => '',
    'message' => $push_message
  ]
];
```

How to handle  it in android fcm please share any suitable solution i want to resolve issue of fcm on background and on foreground ?

Comment: no its not issue of formating i want to handle issue to sending  notification from fcm  but some samsung devices not recive notification  when app is no kill state  like **samsung S8 and S8 plus**

Comment: Dont know how my comment ended up here. That was for my edit of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$payload = [
                        'to' => $user->device_token,
                        'collapse_key'      =>'test message',
                        'data' => [
                        'title' => '',
                        'message' => $push_message
                        ],
                        'notiification' => [
                        'title' => '',
                        'message' => $push_message
                    ]
                ];
```

how to handle  it in android fcm please share any suitable solution  i want to reslove issue of fcm on backround and on foreground